# \begin{align} isn't aligning throughout

Tags: align, alignment

In some part of my `.tex`  file,

```
\begin{align}
\ket{\psi_t}
&= exp(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int _{t_1}^{t_2} \mathbb{H}(t')dt')\ket{\psi_0}= \{ \mathbb{I} -\frac{i}{\hbar}\int _{0}^{t} \mathbb{H}(t')dt' + \frac{1}{2!}(\frac{i}{\hbar})^2 \int _{0}^{t}dt' \int_{0}^{t} dt_1 \mathbb{H}(t_1)\mathbb{H}(t')- \nonumber \\
& \frac{1}{3!}(\frac{i}{\hbar})^3\int _{0}^{t}dt' \int_{0}^{t} dt_1 \int_{0}^{t} dt_2 \mathbb{H}(t_2) \mathbb{H}(t_1)\mathbb{H}(t') + . . .  \ \} \ket{\psi_0} \nonumber \\
& \ket{\psi_t} - \ket{\psi_0} = \{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int _{0}^{t} \mathbb{H}(t')dt' + (\frac{i}{\hbar})^2 \int _{0}^{t}dt' \int_{0}^{t'} dt_1 \mathbb{H}(t_1)\mathbb{H}(t')-   (\frac{i}{\hbar})^3\int _{0}^{t}dt' \int_{0}^{t'} dt_1 \int_{0}^{t_1} dt_2 \mathbb{H}(t_2) \mathbb{H}(t_1)\mathbb{H}(t') \nonumber \\ 
& + . . .  \ \} \ket{\psi_0}
\end{align}
```

gives necessary *Alignment*, but in just other part:

```
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\ket{\psi_t}= -\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathbb{H}(t) 
\{ \mathbb{I} -\frac{i}{\hbar}\int _{0}^{t} \mathbb{H}(t')dt' + \frac{1}{2!}(\frac{i}{\hbar})^2 \int _{0}^{t}dt' \int_{0}^{t} dt_1 \mathbb{H}(t_1)\mathbb{H}(t')- ... \ \} \ket{\psi_0} \nonumber \\
&= -\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathbb{H}(t) \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{H}}\ket{\psi_0}
\end{align}
```

**ALSO**

```
\begin{align}
h(\textbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\textbf{R}_t)}= E_n(\textbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\textbf{R}_t)} \nonumber \\ 
&\implies \braket{\psi_n (\textbf{R}_t)| \psi_m (\textbf{R}_t)}
\end{align}
```

DOESN'T Align the text, rather shifts towards the right-most part.

I am very new to this Latex, and am finding this slightly troublesome, can somebody please note me what exactly am I missing here?
Thank you!

EDIT:

Simply when using `&`:

```
Even take this example, it shifts the `abcd` to the right side

\begin{align}
h(\textbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\textbf{R}_t)}= E_n(\textbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\textbf{R}_t)} \nonumber \\ 
& abcd
\end{align}
```

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The equations align at ampersands (&).  You are missing ampersands in the examples that do not align properly.

Comment: Not, but I have used `&` when I wished to align, but even that doesn't align! That was my question.

Comment: Even take this example, it shifts the `abcd` to the right side
`
\begin{align}
h(\textbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\textbf{R}_t)}= E_n(\textbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\textbf{R}_t)} \nonumber \\ 
& abcd
\end{align}
`

Comment: I have edited and explicitly added the problem, kindly check please!

Comment: The correct markup is `\mathbf{R}` and not `\textbf{R}`. They seem to produce the same, but try `$\textbf{R}$` in the statement of a theorem.

Comment: You don't have an `&` in the first line, so the end of that line will be the alignment point.  That's why the second line is always going all the way to the right.  `align` "matches" the position of the `&` in all lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
     h(\mathbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\mathbf{R}_t)}
  &= E_n(\mathbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\mathbf{R}_t)} \nonumber\\
  &= abcd
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  & h(\mathbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\mathbf{R}_t)}
    = E_n(\mathbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\mathbf{R}_t)} \nonumber\\
  & abcd
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But can I not start this from the leftmost side again?

Comment: @prikarsartam  If you want to align the lines at the left end of the line, place the ampersands at the beginning of each line.

Comment: @prikarsartam, yes you can. As pointed out by N. F. Taussig above, you just move the ampersand of the first line to the place that you want the second line to align to. I just changed my answer to show both cases.

Comment: `\mathbf`, not `\textbf`. Don't confuse them.

Comment: @egreg, you are absolutely right. I have made the correction.

Comment: I didn't know; but including `\begin{split} \end{split}` resolved them all

Answer (score 3):

I have used `braket` package instead of `physics` package. Here I add an alternative with a few small differences.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
     h(\mathbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\mathbf{R}_t)}
  &= E_n(\mathbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\mathbf{R}_t)}\\
  &= abcd\\[1cm]
  h(\mathbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\mathbf{R}_t)}
    & = E_n(\mathbf{R}_t) \ket{\psi_n (\mathbf{R}_t)}\\
  abcd &
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

The snapshot is:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much @Sebastiano for the answer, but I used `\begin{split}` `\end{split}` and it worked fine!

Comment: @prikarsartam Don't worry absolutely. I have given to you an alternative :-). Regards.